# validate text field using regular expression javaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want  to validate a  text  field to  accept  just text  like  this :

- **1,2;2,3;1-3**
- **1-2;4;2,3;4;1-3**
- **12**

I don't want the  types  like this :

- **;1**
- **,1**
- **-1**
- **1;;2**
- **1,,2**
- **1--2**
- **1-2-3**
- **1,2,3**
- **1,2-3**

so I make  this  regular expression but it  seems doesn't work like  what I want

```
var reg = /^\d*(((?!.*--)(?!.*,,)(?!.*;;)(?!.*,;)(?!.*,-)(?!.*-;)(?!.*-,)(?!.*;,)(?!.*;-))[,-;])*\d$/
```

thanks for  your  help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use the regex

```js
function match(str){
    return str.match(/^(?!.*([-,])\d+\1)(?!.*,\d+-)\d+(?:[-,;]\d+)*$/) != null
}

console.log(match(';1'));
console.log(match(',1'));
console.log(match('1;;2'));
console.log(match('1-3'));
console.log(match('12'));
console.log(match('1,2;2,3;1-3'));
console.log(match('1-2;4;2,3;4;1-3'));
console.log(match('1,2,3'));
```

take a look at [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vrt4L4/1)

Comment: thank  you @marvel308 for your response ,is  there any  way to elimanate this case `1,2,3`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
/^\d+(?:(?:[-,;]\d+){3,})?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/peRXSY/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` -  1 or more digits
- `(?:(?:[-,;]\d+){3,})?` - 1 or 0 sequences of:

  - `(?:[-,;]\d+){3,}` - 3 sequences of:

    - `[-,;]` - a `-`, `,` or `;`
    - `\d+`   - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string

```js
var ss = [ '1,2;2,3;1-3','1-2;4;2,3;4;1-3','12',';1',',1','-1','1;;2','1,,2','1--2','1-2-3','1,2,3','1,2-3',';1',',1','-1','1;;2','1,,2','1--2' ];
var rx = /^\d+(?:(?:[-,;]\d+){3,})?$/;
for (var s of ss) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

NOTE: the `[,-;]` creates a range between `,` and `;` and matches much more than just `,`, `-` or `;` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPRzN8/1)).

Comment: thank you  @Wiktor for  your explanation, it  works  fine. I  want to  eliminate this  case  too  `1,3,4`

Comment: @OLH: so, you want to match `1`, `1,3`, or `1,3,4,5` but not `1,3,4`? Please explain the **rule**. Or do you want to avoid matching delimited numbers if they are separated with only 1 type of separator (i.e. if there is a separator, there must be at least 2 different ones)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt. Based on your examples I've assumed that semi-colons are used to separate 'ranges', where a 'range' can be a single number or a pair separated by either a comma or a hyphen.

```js
var re = /^\d+([,\-]\d+)?(;\d+([,\-]\d+)?)*$/;

// Test cases
[
    '1',
    '1,2',
    '1-2',
    '1;2',
    '1,2;2,3;1-3',
    '1-2;4;2,3;4;1-3',
    '12',

    ';1',
    ',1',
    '-1',
    '1;;2',
    '1,,2',
    '1--2',
    '1-2-3',
    '1,2,3',
    '1,2-3'
].forEach(function(str) {
    console.log(re.test(str));
});
```

The first part, `\d+([,\-]\d+)?` matches a 'range' and the second part `(;\d+([,\-]\d+)?)*` allows further 'ranges' to be added, each starting with a semi-colon.

You can add in `?:` to make the groups non-capturing if you like. That's probably a good idea but I wanted to keep my example as simple as I could so I've left them out.